# Scroll page until a div reach the navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need scroll my page when my user click in a button

I'm using the following code

```
$('#content').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#divTicketMedioGrupoProdutos").offset().top
}, 'slow');
```

But, with this code, my page scroll until the `div` is found and get the `top` propertie, and I need that this `div` reach a specific `.offset().top`, i.e. scroll a little bit more until reach my fixed navbar.

How can I make this using scrollTop ?

`Grupo Produto - Ticket Médio` is the title of the `$("#divTicketMedioGrupoProdutos")`, look that right now is so close of my navbar because I scroll the page. I want this when my user click in a button.

**UPDATE**

Look at the image below, when I click on the green bar in the chart, generate a new graph;

[image]

And in the image below, with the code

`$('#content').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#divTicketMedioGrupoProdutos").offset().top
}, 'slow');`

you can see that the page scrolls but the new `div` are in the middle of the page because didn't scroll so much (with the code)

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the div is covered by your fixed nav bar? If so then just get the height of the navbar and add it to the sctollTop value

Comment: @Huangism When I scroll my page, this navbar will be always on the top, always visible. When I click in a specific button, I create a `div`, but nowadays the user need scroll the page to see the created `div`. So, I want change this, to when the user click on the button, the page scroll to the created `div`, but scroll to let the `div` closest to the `navbar` position

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your explanation. I understand that you want the page to automatically scroll to the created div. But after that I don't know where exactly you are trying to scroll to. Create a fiddle

Comment: @Huangism I updated my question with some images to better explain.

Comment: as I understand you, your page will scroll. but not to the correct position. how is it scrolling "wrong"? covered by the navigation? is it not even getting in the viewport? a fiddle would be nice...

Comment: @Lucas_Santos ok so what you need to do is: generate the table, after it is completed and displayed on the page, get the scrollTop of the new table and animate to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding additional pixels to your .offset().top() call?

```
    $('#content').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#divTicketMedioGrupoProdutos").offset().top() + 70
    }, 'slow');
```

Comment: The `offset().top` of my `div` hasn't a fixed value, so, everytime the page is rendered, the `.offset().top` could have a different value